# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ':' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I don't understand what i am doing wrong here

`Test`:

```
Id  |   Roll    |   
-------------------------   
1   |   145 |   


select Id + ':' + roll from test
```

Comment: In SQL Server, `+` means add for all int field, and it will try to convert any text to value (in your case ':').  Which means if your `Id` or `Roll` is int, you need to cast it as text first

Comment: Cast the integer values to char before concatenating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already answered in comments,but for sake of completion,you can do below

```
select cast(Id as varchar(1)) + ':' + cast(roll  as varchar(10)) from test
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness:

People using SQL Server 2012 and up can use [CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) to achieve the same without any explicit conversions.

```
SELECT CONCAT(15, ':', 10);
```

Will also result into:

```
15:10
```

As an added bonus, CONCAT will natively deal with any NULL values instead of killing your result entirely.

```
SELECT CONCAT('Oh snap, there might be a NULL value', NULL, ' somewhere in here!', 11, '!!');
```

Result:

```
Oh snap, there might be a NULL value somewhere in here!11!!
```